# Exception Handling beginner in C#

Tags: c#, exception

I am trying to learn C# on my own. 
In below code I want to execute **main method** only if there is no Exception found.  **Is it possible** ????

Can anyone help me with it

**Code**

```
public abstract class AbsClass
    {
        // Abstract Method
        public abstract int DivTwoNumbers(int a, int b);

    }

    class Program : AbsClass
    {
        public int result { get; set; }

        public override int DivTwoNumbers(int a, int b)
        {
            try
            {
                result = a / b;
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Second Number was " + e.Message);
            }

            return result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AbsClass prog = new Program();
            int div = prog.DivTwoNumbers(10, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Division Of Number Is : {0} ", div);
        }

    }
```

Comment: `Main` method executes first when you start Console Application. If your code throws any exception the application will be terminated.

Comment: `MultTwoNumbers` does `a/b` is that on purpose ? ;-)

Comment: @JesseJames So i guess this is useless question. Right??

Comment: Exceptions should handle when they occur. We can't predict them before executing a main method :)

Comment: @KCdod Thanks. Just a newbie trying to figure out different scenarios

Comment: If I understand you right, you don't want to print number if division is incorrect

Comment: @JesseJames Yes that is what i want. It should only display the Error message.

Comment: you can always check your dividing number for zero before dividing :) if(b!=0){//divide}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`If I understand you right, you don't want to print number if division is incorrect` - from my comment to possible answer.

```
public override int DivTwoNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    return a / b;
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AbsClass prog = new Program();
    try
    {
        int div = prog.DivTwoNumbers(10, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Division Of Number Is : {0} ", div);
    }
    catch (DivideByZeroException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DivideByZeroException. Second Number was " + e.Message);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ErrorMessage :" + ex); // will also print exception details (edit by `KCdod`)
    }

}
```

Comment: Ooppss. That was so easy. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The Main method is always the first to be executed, you must call DivTwoNumbers inside the Main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        DivTwoNumbers(10, 0);
        //continue ...
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //break...
    }
}
```